# Finding highest values in an array within a certain distance of each other

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have an array of ints which represent altitudes, and I need to find out how many of those altitudes will be able to see the horizon to the west (the array is organized from west to east). The requirement for seeing the horizon is being higher than the last n/5 altitudes, where n is the length of the array.

This would be easy with two for loops, but I have to do it in O(n). So I can only iterate over the array once. I don't need a solution, just push in the right direction.

Comment: Two loops are O(n) as long as they are not nested! Actually, any constant number of (simple, non-nested) loops, e.g 10,000,000, is still O(n)

Comment: Post the pseudocode for your current solution, please.

Comment: If you loop the arrow twice, it is O(2n) == O(n)

Comment: @ChristianJonassen - It sounds like they don't know how to start.

Comment: @scibuff - True, but the obvious solution (which I think krispy is referring to) would be one loop forward with a nested loop going backwards n/5 values to find the value to compare to. That solution would be O(n*n/5) = O(n^2)

Comment: @BrendanLong - They need to at least attempt to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about working backwards through the array? Start at the end and create a queue of every altitude you pass. If you see an altitude bigger than the current one, then none of the altitudes in the queue can see the horizon (so you can throw them out). If you get to n/5, then the last altitude in the queue can see the horizon (and obviously, you'll need to handle the case of more than n/5 elements in the queue).

Comment: I can't use data structures, but I managed to achieve the same result using two cursors. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read this
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

An altitude will be able to see the horizon if it is maximum altidude in the sliding window of size = n/5.

"Maximum in sliding (moving) window" problem has O(n) complexity. It is possible to find it's solution both at SO and on the Internet.

Hint: use simple data structures - queues or stacks